# Google Chrome will NOT empty cache

Tags: html, .net, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I have a `.NET Core 3.1` web application and I'm working in `VS Code`.

If I make changes to my HTML or JavaScript, the browser doesn't see the changes when I refresh the page.  This is happening with IE, Firefox and Chrome.  If I stop the project and re-reun it, the changes are there.

I've tried :

- CTRL+F5
- Right click refresh button "Empy Cache and Hard Reload"
- Clearing cache and browser data through settings
- Checking the Disable Cache option in Network tab of DevTools
- Restarting my computer

---

**How can I make the browser see the changes I'm making to my project?**

I don't want to have to constantly stop and start my project for small content changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out.  Turns out that for `.NET Core 3.1` and possibly other versions, you need to install a Nuget package to enable compiling during debug!

- I installed this Nuget package:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` (version 3.1)

- And added this to Startup.cs > Configure Services:

`services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

Everything works the way it should now.